# installing ghmm library on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I am trying to install ghmm (the general hidden markov model) library in Ubuntu 18.04.
For some reason the conda channel is not responding, it is taking forever to finish this `conda install -c bioconda ghmm`.
Is there a reliable source from where I can install ghmm ?

Thanks.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ghmm

Comment: Hey! I found something. Try running `sudo apt-get install build-essential automake autoconf libtool python-dev libxml++2.6-dev swig  subversion
 && svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/ghmm/code/trunk/ghmm ghmm && cd ghmm
sh autogen.sh &&
sudo ./configure;
sudo make;
sudo make install;
sudo ldconfig;`

Comment: Can you kindly write the commands one after the other.

Comment: Just copy/paste it. I've written it in such a way that you can run all the commands in one go by copy-pasting it onto a terminal.